# android gdb fails with "Remote target doesn't support qGetTIBAddr packet" error

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, nox

My app runs fine but gdb fails to debug it with the following error

(gdb) target remote 127.0.0.1:8888
`target:/system/bin/app_process32' has disappeared; keeping its symbols.
Remote debugging using 127.0.0.1:8888
**Remote target doesn't support qGetTIBAddr packet**

I am on Windows 10 64 bit and using nox 32bit emulator.
The following message is displayed when gdbserver is started.

beyond1q:/system/bin # gdbserver :8888 --attach 3805
warning: Found custom handler for signal 39 (Unknown signal 39) preinstalled.
Some signal dispositions inherited from the environment (SIG_DFL/SIG_IGN)
won't be propagated to spawned programs.

what is the solution?